# avcodec_send_frame cause memory leak

Tags: ffmpeg

I found that when avcodec_send_frame return false,then will cause the memory leak.The frame data every time send to encode is about 70MB,so when avcodec_send_frame return false,it cause horrible memory leak.
I want to know how to solve this problem.

```
int ffmpeg_video_encode(int index)
{
    int got_picture = 0;
    int s = sws_scale(scxt, m_pFrameBGR->data, m_pFrameBGR->linesize, 0, m_pVideoCodecCtx->height, m_pFrameYUV->data, m_pFrameYUV->linesize);
    m_pFrameYUV->data[0] = m_pYUVBuf;
    m_pFrameYUV->data[1] = m_pYUVBuf + m_iYPlaneSize;
    m_pFrameYUV->data[2] = m_pYUVBuf + m_iYPlaneSize  + m_iYPlaneSize * 1 / 4;
    m_pFrameYUV->pkt_pts = index * (m_videoStream->time_base.den) / ((m_videoStream->time_base.num) * m_iOutputVideoFPS);

    //av_frame_make_writable(m_pFrameYUV);
    av_init_packet(&m_pktVideo);
    int ret = avcodec_send_frame(m_pVideoCodecCtx, m_pFrameYUV);
    while (ret >= 0)
    {
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(m_pVideoCodecCtx, &m_pktVideo);
        if (AVERROR(EAGAIN) == ret || AVERROR_EOF == ret)
        {
            av_packet_unref(&m_pktVideo);
            av_free_packet(&m_pktVideo);
            return -1;
        }
        else if (ret < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error during encoding\n");
            av_packet_unref(&m_pktVideo);
            av_free_packet(&m_pktVideo);

            return -1;
        }

        m_pktVideo.stream_index = m_videoStream->index;
        ret = av_write_frame(m_pFormatCtx_v, &m_pktVideo);
        av_packet_unref(&m_pktVideo);
        av_free_packet(&m_pktVideo);

    }
    av_free_packet(&m_pktVideo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: avcodec_send_frame always return -11.

Comment: The information of AVEROR* macros is version dependent. You have to interpret it by `av_strerror()`. And I'm not so sure there will be some memory leak. The API user should be responsible for allocating/freeing decoded frame struct.

Comment: Do you take care of freeing `m_pFrameYUV` after each call ?